# How to transfer large database dump VERY FAST from remote aws machine to local machine

Tags: mysql, backup, database-backups

I am using aws amazon machine for my web application. currently my database dump size is 15 GB. I am trying to download database dump with scp command to my local machine. to download 15 GB database dump it is taking around 1 hour.

i want to know the fastest way to download the database dump from remote machine to local machine.

Answer (score 0):

First, ZIP it
Second, you can try to upload it to S3 and then either download it directly from there, or create a CloudFront distribution for that S3 bucket and download it through CloudFront.

I'm not sure that all in all it would be faster (because it would also take time to upload to S3) but it's worth a shot.

Also, if the database contains any personal or sensitive data, keep security in mind if you plan to allow public access to the uploaded file.